# How do I sign extend and then find the value of the unsigned binary number in C?

Tags: c

I have a variable declared as an int

int a = -3;

I want the twos' complement values sign extended to 16 bits. So, it becomes: 1111 1111 1111 1101 and then find the unsigned value of this number, which would be 65533 (I believe).

In other words, I want to go from -3 to 65533.

Following this answer: [Sign extension from 16 to 32 bits in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215256/sign-extension-from-16-to-32-bits-in-c) I'm stuck on the first step. Here's a shortened version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    int s = -3;
    printf("%x\n", s);
    s = (int16_t)s;
    printf("%x\n", s);
    int16_t i = s;
    printf("%x\n", i);

    return(0);
}
```

I compile with gcc test.c and all three printf statements give "fffffffd"

Do you know why the cast isn't working and perhaps any better solutions to the original problem?

Comment: Isn't %x always unsigned? So something like     printf("%hu\n", i);  would print 65533.

Comment: @lundman whether or not %x is signed, wouldn't casting to int16_t shorten the output to only 16 bits?

Comment: `uint16_t u = (uint16_t)(int16_t)s;`

Comment: `printf("%x\n", s);`  %x expects an unsigned int. And: printf() is a varargs-function. Be afraid...

Comment: @Siguza that seems to get it. Do you know if there is a way to directly convert s without renaming a new variable?

Comment: @wildplasser if it interprets "s" as an unsigned int, I think that would be what I want for the last step, unless it does anything else

Comment: you can't "rename" any variables in C. The only way to achieve this is casting to an unsigned type, or just truncating the high bits

Comment: @Goldname well, just use `(uint16_t)(int16_t)s` as an expression...

Comment: @Siguza just `(uint16_t)s` is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you appear to be struggling with the issue is understanding just exactly what bits you are dealing with in interpreting the bits as signed or unsigned or as exact-width types.

> **How do I sign extend and then find the value of the unsigned binary
>   number in C?**

**Answer:** you don't -- the bits never change....

When you declare `int a = -3;`, the bits are set in memory. Thereafter, unless you change them, they are the exact same 32-bits (or whatever `sizeof a` is on your hardware).

The key to understanding sign-extension is it only applies when interpreting a negative value under a two's complement system when casting or assigning to a *larger-size* type. Otherwise, you are not extending anything, you are just *interpreting* the bits as a different type.

A short example for your problem will illustrate. Here `int a = -3;` is declared (defined) and the bits of `a` thereafter never change. However, you can interpret those bits (or by lose analogy look at them from a different viewpoint) and use those bits as `short`, `unsigned short`, `int16_t` or `uint16_t` and in all unsigned cases, interpret them as a hexadecimal value, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <inttypes.h>
#endif

int main (void) {

    int a = -3;

    printf ("a (as int)                     : %d\n"
            "a (as short)                   : %hd\n"
            "a (as unsigned short)          : %hu\n"
            "a (as unsigned short hex)      : 0x%0x\n"
            "a (as PRId16)                  : %" PRId16 "\n"
            "a (as PRIu16)                  : %" PRIu16 "\n"
            "a (as PRIx16)                  : 0x%" PRIx16 "\n",
            a, (short)a, (unsigned short)a, (unsigned short)a,
            (int16_t)a, (uint16_t)a, (uint16_t)a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/exact3
a (as int)                     : -3
a (as short)                   : -3
a (as unsigned short)          : 65533
a (as unsigned short hex)      : 0xfffd
a (as PRId16)                  : -3
a (as PRIu16)                  : 65533
a (as PRIx16)                  : 0xfffd
```

Look things over, and look at all the answers, and let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: `inttypes.h` is part of ISO C

Comment: Yes, but versions of VS don't have it (at least the win7 variety.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code causes undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier for the argument type in printf.

Here is some correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s = -3;
    uint16_t u = s;          // u now has the value 65533

    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)u);
    printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)u);
}
```

The code to printf a `uint16_t` is slightly complicated, it's simpler to cast to `unsigned int` and use `%u` or `%x` which are specifiers for `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

fffffffd is the correct two's complement value it's just being printed in hex 
use `%d` in your printf statements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    int s = -3;
    printf("%d\n", s);
    s = (int16_t)s;
    printf("%d\n", s);
    int16_t i = s;
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return(0);
}
```

and you should see that 65533 value

Comment: that only prints -3

Comment: `int16_t` is a signed type, so it'll sign-extend the value back to int anyway

Comment: @Dash if you change the 3rd line to `s = (uint16_t)`, sign extension won't happen and you get 65533.

Answer (score 0):

In C casting signed value to a wider type automatically extends its sign.
To get a complement value you need to cast your value to appropriate unsigned type:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    int main ()
    {
        int s = -3;
        printf("%x\n", s);
        int16_t s16 = (int16_t)s;
        printf("%hd\n", s16);
        uint16_t c16 = (uint16_t)s16;
        printf("%hu\n", c16);
    }
```

The output I get:

```
    fffffffd
    -3
    65533
```